# Перевод Object к String

Tags: java, swing

Я выбираю данные из `JTable`, возвращаются данные типа `Object`. В последующем мои данные нужно отобразить в `JTextField`.
Но возникла проблема: данные, чтобы они отобразились в `JTextField`, необходимо преобразовать к `String`. Я уже все испробовал и так:

```
Deptno.setText((String) varDeptno);
```

и так:

```
Deptno.setText(String.format(varDeptno));
```

Как всё-таки можно преобразовать `Object`? И исправить ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at appdirectory_views.UpdateDeptFrame.<init>(UpdateDeptFrame.java:66)
    at appdirectory_views.AppDirectoryMainFrame$6.actionPerformed(AppDirectoryMainFrame.java:193)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Код:

```
dbTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {//одинарный щелчок
            int row = dbTable.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
            if (row > -1) {
                int realRow = dbTable.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
                rRow = realRow;
            }
        }
    }
});

public Object getDeptDeptno() {
    Object varDeptno = dbtm.getValueAt(rRow, 0);
    return varDeptno;
}

public Object getDeptDname() {
    Object varDname = dbtm.getValueAt(rRow, 1);
    return varDname;
}

public Object getDeptLoc() {
    Object varLoc = dbtm.getValueAt(rRow, 2);
    return varLoc;
}
```

И во втором фрейме:

```
Object vDeptno = frame15.getDeptDeptno();
Object vDname = frame15.getDeptDname();
Object vLoc = frame15.getDeptLoc();
deptnoField = new JTextField(2);
deptnoField.setText((String)vDeptno);
aField.setText((String)vDeptno);
dnameField = new JTextField(14);
dnameField.setText((String)vDname);
locField = new JTextField(13);
locField.setText((String)vLoc);
```

Comment: А как вы из `JTable` данные берёте? У вас проблема каста `BigDecimal` в `String`

Comment: А почему вы возвращаете в виде `Object`? Как бы то ни было, всегда можно просто вызвать метод `toString()` у объекта и получить строку.

Comment: Regent, не использовал по тому что не знал о нем

Comment: И вы правы, я сделал вот так: `deptnoField.setText(vDeptno.toString());` и все заработало

Comment: @Regent, вот бы вы в ответ это написали... =)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да я ж как обычно - в комментариях :) Но ответ, что примечательно, так никто и оформил, так что я попытался одно предложение из комментария растянуть на целый ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В классе `Object` есть метод [public String toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()), который возвращает текстовое представление объекта.
Метод `toString` в самом классе `Object` возвращает мало полезную для отображения пользователю информацию, однако в некоторых классах он переопределён, и возвращаемое значение вполне наглядно. В том числе и в классе `BigDecimal`, которому, судя по stacktrace, принадлежит `varDeptno`.

Поэтому если написать так:

```
deptnoField.setText(vDeptno.toString());
```

То не придётся приводить объект к какому-либо классу, что порой чревато `ClassCastException`.